# boost thread function inside a protected method

Tags: c++, class, boost

I am new to C++ and boost and would appreciate if you can point out what could be the problem. I am trying to use a boost thread calling a function. I have edited working code to introduce threads.

in .h I have

```
class Base: public test 
{
 public:
    Base(string Name, string test);

    virtual ~Base();


    Base &operator=(const Base &other);

    Base(const Base &other);
 protected:
    virtual void Run();
 private:
    void RunBasic();
    void workerFunc();
 }
```

in the .cpp file I have

```
void Base::Run() 
{
  boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);
  RunBasic();
  workerThread.join();
}

void Base::workerFunc()
{
  #pretending to do some work
  #some functionality here
}

void Base::RunBasic() 
{
 #more stuff here
}
```

I get a compile error `error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that to take the address of the member function you need to say `&Base::workerFunc`

Once you fix that you'll get another error, which is that a non-static member function can't be called without an object, so you need to pass an object (or pointer to an object) to the `thread` constructor:

```
boost::thread workerThread(&Base::workerFunc, this);
```

This tells the `thread` object to create a new thread and then run `this->workerFunc()`, so that should work now.

If the function had arguments you would pass them after the `this` parameter:

```
boost::thread workerThread(&Base::workerFunc, this, arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `workerFunc` is a member function, you'll have to bind it to the thread.

```
boost::thread workerThread(&Base::workerFunc, this);
```

Comment: No, `boost::thread` implements the _INVOKE_ protocol, so `bind` is redundant, just `boost::thread workerThread(&Base::workerFunc, this)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was unaware of that, I have edited my answer.