# Passing parameter to boost::thread no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

From the boost::thread documentation it seems that I can pass parameters to the thread function by doing this:

```
boost::thread* myThread = new boost::thread(callbackFunc, param);
```

However, when I do this the compiler complains that

> no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

My code:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
void Game::playSound(sf::Sound* s) {
    boost::thread soundThread(playSoundTask, s);
    soundThread.join();
}

void Game::playSoundTask(sf::Sound* s) {
    // do things
}
```

I am using the copy of boost that came with Ogre3d, which I suppose could be very old. Interestingly, though, I took a look at thread.hpp and it does have the templates for constructors with 2 or more parameters.

Comment: Your first problem is trying to initialize a `thread` object with a `thread*`, but your error is unrelated – it sounds like you're either missing `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` or using a **really** old version of Boost...

Comment: Can you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @ildjarn, ah silly me. I made a typo when describing my code. I'll update the question with my actual code and some more information

Comment: Is `Game` a class or a namespace?

Comment: @RazorStorm Ah OK, that explains it. I edited my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost thread function inside a protected method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251609/boost-thread-function-inside-a-protected-method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that member functions take an implicit first parameter `Type*`, where `Type` is the type of the class. This is the mechanism by which member functions get called on instances of types, and means you have to pass an extra parameter to the `boost::thread` constructor. You also have to pass the address of the member function as `&ClassName::functionName`.

I have made a small compiling and running example that I hope illustrates the use:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  void foo(int i) 
  {
    std::cout << "foo(" << i << ")\n";
  }
  void bar()
  {
    int i = 42;
    boost::thread t(&Foo::foo, this, i);
    t.join();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.bar();
}
```

Comment: @VisionIncision `boost::thread(the_function, arg0, arg1, arg2, ....)`. There are plenty of posts about this on the web.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. There must be something else amiss. Thanks anyway. I shall investigate further.